# Creating Virtual Host on apache not loading styles from root directory

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, digital-ocean

I am new to VPS hosting.... and giving a try to digital ocean Linux VPS. I need to point 2 domains to my PHP app.

This is how my Virtual Host looks like inside /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@domain1.com
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

However... I am not able to load my styling and access any files or directories that is in var/www/html directory. How can I enable the permissions for my domains to access these resources.

Similarly my second Virtual host for another domain

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app/login.php
```

Everything seems working while I am accessing the site using the IP...However... after setting up virtual host... the content is loading but can not access css and js... in the current root directory.

I am not sure what I need to do to set up my domains as expected.

I am using ../ notation to point my previous directory. There is no error with the site that is showing...just not loading CSS. Also I have the APIs in the root directory.... inside API folder.... that is not accessible while I am pointing them ../../API/v1/create_user.php

Comment: Can you pls add some info? How do you include the css file?

Comment: "I am not able to load my styling and access". Which error do you get? What does the server error log say about those requests?

Comment: @Johannes Edited post. There is no error.... I just can't access files in previous directories using ../